# LibreOffice-writer : Can I add shortcut-key for special characters?

Tags: shortcut-keys, libreoffice, special-characters

In ms-office-word shortcut-key for special characters can be applied as following:

[image]

**But now I am using Libre-office Which is pre-installed with Ubuntu! and want to put shortcut-key for special characters**. But there is not such option available:

[image]

It is difficult for me to write every-time with Unicode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>then<kbd>055</kbd>then<kbd>Enter</kbd>(*0055 is only example for U which is not special-character*).

Thus, Help me to add shortcut-key or any other method as I am leaving ms-office and working with libre-office Version: 4.2.3.3 (open-source and pre-installed with Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: It's done through the desktop environment, not through LibreOffice itself.

Comment: +1 for Sparhawks comment. [Here's a tutorial](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47496/how-can-i-add-a-custom-compose-key-sequence) on setting up custom compose sequences. Another option would be to use [LO's autocorrect](http://askubuntu.com/questions/201960/how-do-you-write-a-macro-for-a-special-character-in-libreoffice/201967).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to solve this with the built in tools.

Nevertheless, I use [AutoKey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/) to insert text snippets like my address system wide. I guess you could just add a snippet containing the special character and set up a shortcut for it. AutoKey offers a lot of configuration possibilities for triggering snippets.

As my system is broken in the moment, I can't test it. Hope it helps anyways.

Comment: The snippets I am talking about are actually called "Phrases" in AutoKey. Here is a nice tutorial: http://saravananthirumuruganathan.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/autokey-linux-utility-for-text-substitution-hotkeys-and-desktop-automation/